# tidyverse: Multiple plots for each level of a factor or each value of a numeric variable

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse, purrr

I want to make multiple plots for each level of a factor or each value of a numeric variable (here each value of `vs` variable). I do not want to use `facet_grid` or `facet_wrap`. I wonder if there is a more compact way to accomplish the task. In my actual data I do have many levels of a factor.

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::filter(vs == 0) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()


mtcars %>% 
  dplyr::filter(vs == 1) %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe doing it like that?

```
plot_list <- map(.x = unique(mtcars$vs), ~ mtcars %>% 
              dplyr::filter(vs == .x) %>% 
              ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
              geom_point() +
              ggtitle(.x))

plot_list[[1]]
```

Comment: Thanks @Humpelstielzchen for your answer.  Your code throws the following error: `Error in if (length(ans) == 0L || as.character(ans[[1L]])[1L] == "~") { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Any thoughts, please.

Comment: Do you get the error on the `mtcars` dataset or on your data?

Comment: Works fine after restarting R session. Thanks

Comment: Always glad to help

Comment: It would be nice if you guide how to put title reflecting the value of `vs`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `group_by`, `nest`, `purrr::pwalk` to walk over the nested list of dataframes passing the grouping variable and the filtered dataframe to the custom function inside the pwalk call.

```
plot_vs <- function(vs, data){ 
g1<-
  data %>% 
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()+
  ggtitle(!!vs)
print(g1)
}


mtcars %>% 
    group_by(vs) %>% 
    nest() %>% 
    purrr::pwalk(plot_vs)
```